# random shutdown since clean install of xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

I've just did a fresh install of xubuntu 15.04 and since then my laptop constantly shuts down without warning like pullig the plug so there is nothing in logs.
Temperatures are normals.
Everything was fine under 14.04.
Sometimes it runs ok all day but usually shuts down after about 30min+.
Going back to 14.04.2 gives me the same problem. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens due to overheating. Maybe something is wrong with the temperature sensors. Lets try to check this out:

Install the program lm-sensors (run in terminal).

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Detect all sensors (run in terminal):

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Get temperature data (run in terminal):

```
sensors
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As I said temperatures are ok. Between 40 and 50°C when it happens.